# How to calculate a value based on other text field in OAF

Tags: oaf

How to calculate the value in amount field based on receipt quantity*unit price, at the same instant without navigating to the next page.

I am trying to calculate Amount based on (Receipt Quantity *unit price) in iProcurement module in EBS. I have currently written the code for its calculation in ProcessformRequest, but it works only when I press on the Next button and come back to see the amount.

```
 OAApplicationModule   am = (OAApplicationModule)pageContext.getRootApplicationModule();
    OAViewObject          vo = (OAViewObject)am.findViewObject("ReceiveMyItemsVO");

for (XxuaReceiveMyItemsVORowImpl voRow = (XxuaReceiveMyItemsVORowImpl)vo.first(); voRow != null; voRow = (XxuaReceiveMyItemsVORowImpl)vo.next()) {
            // get info from current line
            oracle.jbo.domain.Number  xup = voRow.getXxuaUnitPrice();
            oracle.jbo.domain.Number   rq = voRow.getReceiptQuantity();
            oracle.jbo.domain.Number xa   = null;

xa = xup.multiply (rq);
}
```

Now my requirement is, as soon as I give the receipt quantity and press on tab , the amount should be calculated without going to next page. Is there any change event that we can use to perform this.

Answer (score 0):

Can you have a button next to 'Receipt Qty', which you may call 'Calculate Amount'. In your processformRequest method, check if the acling action is that new button, then perform that calculation and have a statement like below:
.setAttribute('',);

So the user will be supposed to explicitly click on new button to have calculated value displayed.